# Create and mount subdirectories in exported NFS directory in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

I have a fileserver with a folder `/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/`. Inside this folder, I have subdirectories for every user of my application:

- `/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerA`
- `/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerB`
- `/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerC`

Inside each customer folder, I have two folders for the applications of my data stores:

- `/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerA/elastic`
- `/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerA/postgres`

I have a Kubernetes configuration file that specifies persistent volumes and claims. These mount to the `elastic` and `postgres` folders.

```
# Create a volume on the NFS disk that the postgres db can use. 
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  namespace: customerA
  name: postgres-pv
  labels:
    name: postgres-volume 
spec:
  storageClassName: manual 
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  nfs:
    server: 1.2.3.4 # ip addres of nfs server
    path: "/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerA/postgres" 

---

# And another persistent volume for Elastic
```

Currently, my `/etc/exports` file looks like this:

```
/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerA/postgres 10.0.0.1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerA/elastic 10.0.0.1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerA/postgres 10.0.0.2(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerA/elastic 10.0.0.2(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)


/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerB/postgres 10.0.0.1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerB/elastic 10.0.0.1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerB/postgres 10.0.0.2(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/customerB/elastic 10.0.0.2(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

For every customer, I explicitly export a `postgres` and `elastic` folder separately for every node in my Kubernetes cluster. This works as intended. However, I now have to manually add rows to the `etc/exports` file for every new customer. Is it possible to have just two lines like this:

```
/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/ 10.0.0.1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/ 10.0.0.2(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

And automatically have Kubernetes create the correct sub-directories (customer, postgres and elastic) inside the `kubernetes-volumes` directory and mount them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes can't perform system commands on nodes by itself, you need to use some external tool, such as bash script.

You can use only the path `/mnt/kubernetes-volumes/` in you containers and using environment variable you can pass the customer name, but it will make all data acessible by all other pods, and isn't a good idea.

Also, you could try to use [HELM templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started/) to create your `persistentVolumes` using the name of your customers as variables.

Comment: Thanks, a shell script is trivial so I'll stick to that solution.